Network trace an internal domain that is setup to access an external site
I am not a network person but need to track or understand the following.  We have a legacy flow that I am trying to understand/reverse-engineer.
Use-case:

Public end user makes call to application web tier behind firewall.
Internal Web tier matches on the URI on a reverse proxy rule
The reverse proxy rule is directed to https://123.abc.com/theURI/theResourceIwant.js that is an INTERNAL domain e.g. 10.n.n.n.
The INTERNAL domain url is somehow configured to access an EXTERNAL site e.g. https://publicdomain.com/theURI/theResourceIwant.js and the content is fetched.  I can 'curl' this using the url from 3 which returns the content from URL in 4.

For item #3 and #4, I suspect there is a DNS table, FW rule, something networky or lower level than app, but need to know where and how to look and appreciate your assistance!
Sincerely,
Did a curl command from internal web tier to the internal domain 123.abc.com to a known external resource and was able to get the file (it is just a static js file).
Now, I just need to understand/lookup how this path or redirection from the internal domain 123.abc.com to the external site is implemented and where, e.g. a dns file, a fw rule a...

What do you mean by "internal domain"? Are you referring to split-brain DNS - or to an Active Directory domain? or something else?

I definitely don't have the right naming/terminology and can describe by behavior only...  The company internal web server is Reverse Proxy configured matching on URI to an internal domain e.g. 123.xyz.com (IP is internal 10.n.n.n).  The internal web server URL becomes something like this internal https://123.xyz.com/theuripath/theresourceIwant.js and somehow it auto-magically reaches out to the EXTERNAL public site https://publicsite/theuripath/theresourceIwant.js, and the resource is fetched.  I am trying to understand the 'magic'.
